# Fail to draw plot because of a specific Japanese character in local rstudio and r ui but no probelm in rstudio.cloud using plotly

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly

Fail to show the plot(blank in viewer) with my rstudio and Rui with code:

```
a <- c("予約","リスト")
b <- c(20,30)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
plot_ly(df, x = ~a, y = ~b,type = 'bar')
```

But with same code the plot can be shown correctly in rstudio.cloud.
When I delete the character "予" in `a` like below, the plot can be shown correctly.

```
a <- c("約","リスト")
b <- c(20,30)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
plot_ly(df, x = ~a, y = ~b,type = 'bar')
```

I change the R version to 3.6.0 (the current version of rstudio.cloud)but still can not show.

```
rstudio version: 1.2.5001
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems to work fine in my local RStudio (RStudio version 1.2.1578, R 3.6.0 Beta). Maybe try running in a fresh R Session?

Comment: In my env, I can reproduce this problem. I think it happens on windows OS (CP932 env).

Comment: That would make sense, i'm running it on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is an Encoding problem.
`iconv(Japanese, to = "UTF-8")` can solve it.

```
a <- c("予約","リスト")
b <- c(20, 30)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

plot_ly(df, x = ~ iconv(a, to = "UTF-8"), y = ~ b, type = 'bar')

# or

df2 <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(a = iconv(a, to = "UTF-8"))

plot_ly(df2, x = ~ a, y = ~ b, type = 'bar')
```